# Can we use Mat-card with Anchor Tag?

Tags: css, angular, typescript, angular-material, mat-card

I want to make mat-card to be clickable and when I hover over the mat-card I wanted to show link cursor. There are many cards when I click on one of the cards I want to navigate to another page. How Can I achieve this?

Is it appropriate to use the following code in my template html.

```
<a mat-card   routerLink= ...>  Buy  </a>
```

My first attempt was

```
        <div fxLayout="row rap">
           <mat-card> 
                <mat-card-content> 
                   <div> $100 </div> 
                   <div> 3000 ETB</div>
               </mat-card-content> 
           </mat-card>
        <mat-card> .... </mat-card>
     </div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by the link cursor? Do you mean `cursor: pointer`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HTML

```
<mat-card (click)="redirect(100)"> 
    <mat-card-content> 
        <div> $100 </div> 
        <div> 3000 ETB</div>
    </mat-card-content> 
</mat-card>

<mat-card (click)="redirect(200)"> 
    <mat-card-content> 
        <div> $200 </div> 
        <div> 4000 ETB</div>
    </mat-card-content> 
</mat-card>
```

CSS

```
mat-card {
  cursor: pointer;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}
```

TS

```
redirect(id) {
    alert('Called from ' + id);
  }
```

Working Solution : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zr3tqo

Answer (score 6):

`<a *ngFor="let card of childCards" [routerLink]="[card?.targetUrl]">`

Write mat card code inside anchor tag.

Comment: This is the best solution in the universe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not wrap the mat-card in a `<a>` but sure to remove the underline styling on it

relevant **HTML**:

```
<a class='removeStyle' href='#'>
    <mat-card class="example-card">
    ....
    </mat-card>
</a>
```

relevant **CSS**:

```
.removeStyle{
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

complete [working stackblitz here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtp3ts)

Comment: you're right, the example I used had buttons, but the questioner wants to use only content, no `<mat-card-actions>`

Comment: For me anchor tag worked without removing the styling inside the mat-card tag.